# How to register an ashx handler through sharepoint 2010 farm solution

Tags: 2010, development, web-config, spwebconfigmodification, solution-deployment

I have a 3rd party control that i want to add to the web part.  That 3rd party control uses a generic ASHX handler.  I can always add the registration to the actual WFE web.config but it's a bit manual to my tastes.  Does anyone succeeded to add to web.config using a deployment package?
i would need something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
      <remove name="SomeHandler" />
      <add name="SomeHandler" preCondition="IntegratedMode" 
           verb="GET" path="SomeHandler.ashx" type="SomeHandler, SomeHandler" />
   </handler>
</system.webServer>
```

**Update**
Here is the code that I ended up creating in the feature receiver:

```
var modifications = new List<SPWebConfigModification>()
                    {
                            new SPWebConfigModification("remove[@name='BotDetectCaptachHandler'",
                                                        "configuration/system.webServer/handlers")
                            {
                                Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode,
                                Value = @"<remove name='BotDetectCaptchaHandler'/>"
                            },
                            new SPWebConfigModification("add[@name='BotDetectCaptchaHandler'",
                                                        "configuration/system.webServer/handlers")
                            {
                                Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode,
                                Value = @"<add name='BotDetectCaptchaHandler' preCondition='integratedMode' verb='GET' path='BotDetectCaptcha.ashx' type='BotDetect.Web.CaptchaHandler, BotDetect' />"
                            }
                    };

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges( () =>
                         {
                               var contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;
                               foreach (var modification in modifications)
                               {
                                   contentService.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);
                                }
                                contentService.Update();
                                contentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
                          });
```

When I do activate i get an error message saying that i have previously queue modifications failing to execute.  Does anyone know how to query queued modifications and remove them?  I tried PowerShell but was not successful. It seems that SPWebApplication.WebConfigModifications collection is always empty.

Comment: I think you might need to make sure you are setting the owner on those modifications so when you deactivate the feature the web.config changes get undone.  I realize i forgot to put that in my code below.

Comment: @SteveLineberry, good point. I figured if I leave the owner portion out, it'll assign the default value and that value is used during deactivation.  My problem now is that i have trouble finding those queued up modifications b/c error is talking about configuration/SafeControls/... and i am not even setting that portion of the config. I am chasing ghosts for now ! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a SPWebConfigModification:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx

Something similar to this:

```
SPWebConfigModification handlerMod = new SPWebConfigModification();
handlerMod.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/handlers";
handlerMod.Name = "add[@name='SomeHandler'][@type='SomeHandler']";
handlerMod.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
handlerMod.Value = "<add name=\"SomeHandler\" preCondition=\"IntegratedMode\" verb=\"GET\" path=\"SomeHandler.ashx\" type=\"SomeHandler, SomeHandler\" />";
```

Comment: +1 however it is worth mentioning that this will need to be deployed in a web application scoped feature. Also, be *very careful* with SPWebConfigModification. I would highly recommend reading [Mark Wagner's entire blog post](http://blog.crsw.com/2007/09/20/how-to-modify-the-web-config-file-in-sharepoint-using-spwebconfigmodification/). Make sure you test it in DEV first!

Comment: Yes. I ended up working on that. I'll post a follow up shortly as web config modifications are the most tedious and error prone.

Comment: @Steve Lineberry, the only issue that i have at this point is that for some reason web.config modification logic reorders the modifications.  In handler's section, doing a remove followed by add is normal, and I cannot achieve it.